# Https server based on Java's HttpsServer closes connection during handshake

Tags: java, https

I'm trying to write an https server using Java's built-in HttpsServer class and I get the following exception when trying to connect to the server I wrote using the HttpsURLConnection class:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.jav
```

The client code:

```
private void downloadFromUrl(URL url, String localFilename) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    //System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", '/etc/keystore.ks');
    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "passphrase");
    try 
    {

        char[] passphrase = "passphrase".toCharArray();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, passphrase);

        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, passphrase);

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        ssl.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = new ClientHostnameVerifier();
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier);
        HttpsURLConnection urlSecureConn  = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();//connect
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(ssl.getSocketFactory());

        inputStream = urlSecureConn.getInputStream();               //get connection inputstream
        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFilename);   //open outputstream to local file

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];              //declare 4KB buffer
        int len;

        //continue downloading and storing to local file while data is available
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {  
            fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (inputStream != null) 
            {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } 
        finally 
        {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) 
            {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the code that initializes the https server:

```
public void init()
{
    if(mServer == null)
    {
        try
        {
            InetSocketAddress socket = new InetSocketAddress(Integer.parseInt(LISTENED_PORT));
            mServer = HttpsServer.create(socket, 0);
            updateContexts();
            createContentsFile();
            mServer.createContext("/info.xml", new InfoXMLHandler());
            //mServer.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
            mServer.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(createSslContext()) {
                public void configure (HttpsParameters params) {
                    SSLContext c = null;
                    try
                    {
                        c = getSSLContext();

                        SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters = c.getDefaultSSLParameters ();
                        params.setSSLParameters ( defaultSSLParameters );

                        SSLParameters sslparams = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();
                        params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }
                });
            mServer.start();


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception at server initialization: " + e);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        updateContexts();
    }
}
```

I've googled the issue but i didn't find anything helpful